# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I try and build my project I get the following errors:

```
1>Assignment1CoreTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct point * __cdecl findLongPaths(struct point *,double)" (?findLongPaths@@YAPAUpoint@@PAU1@N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Geometry_CoreUnitTest::test_method(void)" (?test_method@Geometry_CoreUnitTest@@QAEXXZ)
1>Assignment1CoreTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl calculateLineLength(struct point *)" (?calculateLineLength@@YANPAUpoint@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Geometry_CoreUnitTest::test_method(void)" (?test_method@Geometry_CoreUnitTest@@QAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Assignment1\Debug\Assignment1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I've been trying to work out why for the last hour or so and have made absolutely no progress so I was wondering if anyone might be able to point me in the right direction. Obviously I'm doing something stupid but I can't work out what.

This is my AssignmentOneCoreTest.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Test_Assignment1

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "geometry.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Geometry_CoreUnitTest) {
    point p[3] = {{0,0}, {0,3}, {0,1, true}};
    point longest[2] = {{0,1}, {0,3,true}};
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(calculateLineLength(p), 5);

    point *longest_calculated = findLongPaths(p, 1.1);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(longest_calculated[1].y, longest[1].y);
    delete longest_calculated;
}
```

Geometry.cpp:

```
#include "geometry.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

double calculateLineLength(point *points)
{
    ...
}

point *findLongPaths(point *points, double threshold_distance)
{
    ...
}
```

and Geometry.h:

```
#ifndef GEOMETRY_H
#define GEOMETRY_H

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    bool end;
} point;

double calculateLineLength(point *points);
point *findLongPaths(point *points, double threshold_distance);

#endif
```

I'm totally stumped and starting to get kinda frustrated, what am I overlooking?

Comment: It's clear that AssignmentOneCoreTest.cpp is being compiled, but it appears that Geometry.cpp is not. How are you building? From the command line? Within VS?

Comment: Is the power on? Um, I mean, is Geometry.o included in the linking?

Comment: Yep, within VS. I'm just going build -> build solution.

Comment: How can I check if Geometry.o is included?

Comment: @Sam : Is Geometry.cpp listed in your solution's source files? If so, in its properties, is `File Type` set to `C/C++ Code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting linker error. 
Most probably you are not generating the object code for `Geometry.cpp`

this would work for now:

1. create an empty project;
2. copy the header files in the headerfiles folder
3. copy the cpp files in the cpp files folder

then build the project;

this will build your Geometry.cpp program as well.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Is it just a bug with VS or something?

Comment: nopes... not a bug. just a matter of settings. you'll know more as you use VS.